# Start Activity from a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am French but I'll try to explain my problem I have a ListView and in this ListView I'd like to start DIFFERENT activity, I explained :
The first two Items must launch a PDF but the third " Sur Facebook" must to launch a new activity, specifically a new view (facebook.java), I can do it with a button but I can not since my ListView , here is my code :

```
    package com.androiddev.tab;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
...

public class Tab5 extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
private ListView maListViewPerso25;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                setContentView(R.layout.onglet5);

                Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonSelector2);
                button.setOnClickListener(this);


                maListViewPerso25 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView25);
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem25 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                HashMap<String, String> map;
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("titre", "1 - Qui sommes-nous ?");
                map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.fleche));
                map.put("file", "QSN.pdf");
                listItem25.add(map);
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("titre", "2 - A propos de l'application");
                map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.fleche));
                map.put("file", "Apropos.pdf");
                listItem25.add(map);
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("titre", "3 - Sur Facebook");
                map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.fleche));
                listItem25.add(map);
                SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter (this.getBaseContext(), listItem25, R.layout.afichageitem,
                  new String[] {"img", "titre" }, new int[] {R.id.fleche, R.id.titre});
                maListViewPerso25.setAdapter(mSchedule);


                //LISTENER


                maListViewPerso25.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                         HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) maListViewPerso25.getItemAtPosition(position);
                         String nomFichierDansAsset = map.get("file");
                         String nomFichierTemp = "list25.pdf";


                         if (copyAssetToTempFile(nomFichierDansAsset, nomFichierTemp)) {
                          try {
                                String name = getFileStreamPath(nomFichierTemp).getAbsolutePath();
                                Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + name);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                                startActivity(intent);
                          } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                // Cas d'erreur si pas de lecteur PDF installé
                                Log.d("xx", "Erreur affichage PDF", e);
                          }
                        }
                  }
                 });


                 };
  private boolean copyAssetToTempFile(String nomFichierAsset,
           String nomFichierTemp) {
           boolean result = true;
           try {
                 byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
                 FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(nomFichierTemp, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                 InputStream is = getAssets().open(nomFichierAsset);
                 int bytesRead = is.read(buffer);
                 while (bytesRead > 0) {
                   fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                   bytesRead = is.read(buffer);
                 }
                 fos.close();
                 is.close();
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 // Cas d'erreur de création de fichier
                 Log.d("xx", "Erreur creation fichier ", e);
                 result = false;
           } catch (IOException e) {
                 // Cas d'erreur de lecture de fichier
                 Log.d("xx", "Erreur lecture fichier", e);
                 result = false;
           }
           return result;
         }  
// POUR LE BOUTON
  public void onClick(View src) {
         Intent i = new Intent(this, TabAndroidActivity.class);
         startActivity(i);
  };
  }
```

Comment: This is a large chunk of code without any context of the error - you could explain what isn't working, or post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Trace, log or debug to determine what's happening. Btw, don't do long operations in the UI thread of android. This thread is used to paint stuff on screen and react to user inputs, if you use it, as you do to copy files, or other somewhat lenthy operations, you will get ANR on many devices. Learn async tasks

Comment: Sorry for this long code I just want when I click on "3 - Sur Facebook" launches a new view , new activity (facebook.java).
So I want to know how i can do that

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
if(map.get("titre").equals("YourTile") {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Tab5.this, "Your Facebook Activity Here".class);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do first thing in `onItemClick`

```
if(map.get("titre").equals("3 - Sur Facebook") {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, TabAndroidActivity.class));
    return;
}
```

This is ugly but if it is what you're looking for then you will be able to do it better